# How to prevent intellisense from automatically adding column before prop (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, intellisense, vuejs3, vetur

I've been battling this issue for a while now. Does anyone know how to prevent intellisense (in VSCode) from adding column on autocomplete?

I have my custom  component and this is how my intellisense autocompletes my component's props.

- The extension is Vetur v0.34.1 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur).
- I do not have a config for vetur setup.

```
<script lang="ts">
 import { toRefs, defineComponent } from 'vue';

 export default defineComponent({
   name: 'Grid',
   props: {
     alignItems: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
      validator: (val: string): boolean => ['start', 'center', 'end', 'stretch'].includes(val),
   },
   ...
 }
</script>
```

[image]

> > > > **UPDATE**

So I was able to generate the correct IntelliSense autocomplete after generating Tags and Attributes for each component ([followed this step-by-step solution for autogenerating tags and attributes for custom components](https://itnext.io/vue-intellisense-in-vscode-33cf8860e092)).

> NOW

How do I disable autocomplete that is incorrect?

[image]

> > > > **UPDATE**
> > > > Uninstalled Vetur and
> > > > switched to this [volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) and everything works like a charm with Typescript.

Comment: This is clearly a problem of VSCode (or more likely the plugin you are using for Vue). So I doubt anyone will be able to help you without you sharing the info about the plugins you are using (and probably also it's configuration)

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my question. Good catch 

Comment: Just to be clear do you mean the colon sign ":"? Do you want to use the v-bind instead?

Comment: No v-bind. I just want to make intellisense to autocomplete prop with a string, as default value.

Comment: I would think that `type=String` would get picked up by Vetur and adjust intellisense autocomplete automatically but apparently, I need to somehow set it manually

Comment: You can answer your own question in a separate answer and accept it if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much overhead with [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) led me to just simply switch to [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) extension which supports Typescript out of the box and this resolved all my issues